# Resources about making data visualization more accessible to blind people or people with other visual impairments?

Tags: data-visualization, references

I was wondering if there were good resources or references to improve the accessibility of various kinds of data visualization (plots, charts, networks, tables, maps, etc.), for blind people or people with other vision impairment. For example, I'm already aware of tools to make data visualization friendlier to color-blind people.

Are there other tools or references similar to that? In particular, I'd be interested in references explaining how to write good alternative texts for people using screen readers.

Comment: Good question. A common term for your last part is "alt text", and [a search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22alt+text%22+data+visualization) does turn up a number of potentially interesting hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am thinking about this reference, which addresses the choice of color palette to make scientific publications accessible to people with colour-vision deficiency:

[Crameri, F., Shephard, G. E., & Heron, P. J. (2020). The misuse of colour in science communication. Nature communications, 11(1), 5444.](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-19160-7)

Rainbow-like color maps, like `Jet`, should be avoided, as they have the same intensity in red and green. They have no uniformity (neither in color nor in luminosity) and can thus be ill interpreted. Other color palettes, like `Batlow` or the ones presented in Figure 2, should be favored.

**EDIT** Some other references:

- [Making data visualization more accessible for blind and low-vision individuals (MIT News)](https://news.mit.edu/2022/data-visualization-accessible-blind-0602)
- [Data for all: Tactile graphics that light up with picture-perfect resolution (Science)](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abq2640)
- [Fixing figures for color blindness (Nature)](https://media.nature.com/original/magazine-assets/d41586-021-02696-z/d41586-021-02696-z.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! Could you point to any resources about accessibility for more severe vision impairments, like blindness, as J-J-J asked about?

Comment: I just edited my answer, adding some other ressources

Comment: Merci Camille! The tactile graphics look very promising.

Comment: Thanks for the additional refs